# Protect GraphQl queries and mutations with middleware

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I'm developing an express app and experimenting with graphql. I've started to not using old endpoints I made before. The problem is some of my old endpoints protected by middlewares like:

```
router.get(
  "/",
  [auth.verifyToken, auth.checkRole(["role1", "role2"])],
  someController.getAllThings
);
```

So my question is how to protect queries and mutations with middlewares?

Answer (score 1):

In graphql you usually have a single endpoint where your graphql server is running and you provide a context function to your server that is invoked for every incoming request. This is where you can perform authentication/authorization. The context function is passed a `request` object that you can use to verify token and check for user roles. The result of this context function is available to all the resolvers so you can decide which queries or mutations need to protected.

Comment: Do you mind providing example, especially for the dummy endpoint I provided? I'm a bit new to GraphQl.

Comment: Can I still use my middlewares, or will they become useless?

Comment: The way you provide context function depends on how you have setup your graphql server. If you are using apollo server you can find few examples [here](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication).

Comment: I'm using express-graphql.

Comment: I have not used `express-graphql` but it seems like it does support providing a context value when creating a server. You can also pass your auth middleware before mounting your server as described [here](https://graphql.org/graphql-js/authentication-and-express-middleware/). Do note that `express-graphql` has been deprecated.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. I'm refactoring my code to use apollo server.

Answer (score 0):

In GraphQL world the role middleware is somewhat replaced by directives. So if we think of a mutation or a query as an endpoint in an express server if we want to for example add a function that would check if a user is authenticated, then we would make an `isAuth` [directive](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/directives/).

In GraphQL we use a special `@` character for directives.

Let's say we have a query that returns the authenticated user data.

```
const typeDefs = `#graphql

  type Query {
    me: User @isAuth
  }

  type User {
    id: Int
    username: String
  }
`;

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    me() {
      return {
        id: 1,
        username: "exampleUser"
      };
    },
  },
};
```

As you can see we apply the directive directly to the query [field definition](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/schema/schema/).

Now let's make an example of the `@isAuth` directive. First we add the directive to the schema.

```
const typeDefs = `#graphql

  directive @isAuth on FIELD_DEFINITION
  
  type Query {
    me: User @isAuth
  }

  type User {
    id: Int
    username: String
  }
`;
```

This let's GraphQL know that an `isAuth` directive exists.

Next comes the transformer function, which holds your authentication logic.

```
function authenticatedDirectiveTransformer(schema, directiveName) {
  return mapSchema(schema, {
    // Executes once for each object field in the schema
    [MapperKind.OBJECT_FIELD]: (fieldConfig) => {
      // Check whether this field has the specified directive
      const authorizationDirective = getDirective(schema, fieldConfig, directiveName)?.[0];

      if (authorizationDirective) {
        // Get this field's original resolver
        const { resolve = defaultFieldResolver } = fieldConfig;

        // Replace the original resolver with a function that *first* calls
        // the original resolver, then runs your auth logic
        fieldConfig.resolve = async function (source, args, context, info) {
          // Your authentication logic...
          return resolve(source, args, context, info);
        };
        return fieldConfig;
      }
    },
  });
}
```

What the above transformer function basically does is it look for the `isAuth` directive on object fields (Query object, Mutation object, ...) on every GraphQL operation and if it finds it, it will run the `resolve` function with your logic inside.

The last thing we need to do is to apply the transformer function to the GraphQL schema.

```
let schema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
});

// Transform the schema by applying directive logic
schema = authenticatedDirectiveTransformer(schema, 'isAuth');
```